# Real time timer

Tags: python

I am new to Python so be gentle.

I have been trying to write a program that counts or measures events in real time. At the moment I am using the sleep command but this pause event doesn't take into account the time the program takes to run. I have read up on the `datetime` module and can sort of see how this could be used, but I am a bit stuck in implementing this.

In short, I want a program that counts from 0 to 100 in real time seconds and milliseconds.

Comment: This question might be closed. http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy

Comment: You might take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388967/limiting-fps-in-python) about frame rate limiting. Basically, you need to consider that the sleep time can be variable.

Comment: What kind of real time events are you trying to measure?

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet (besides Googling for help before posting a question on SO) might be to do something like this:

- Note the time when the program starts. `start = datetime.datetime.now()`
- Do your calculations
- `sleep` until 100 seconds after `start`. (`start + datetime.timedelta(seconds=100)`)

  - Note that this won't be perfect, since there is a little overhead involved with the steps between accessing the "current time" and going to "sleep" (e.g. subtracting "current time" from "wake-up time"). However, if your sleep precision only needs to be in seconds, you should be okay.
- Repeat as needed.

If, *after trying it out*, you need additional help with the actual implementation of these steps, feel free to come back and post another question on that topic.